# Manga where MC is kicked out from a royal wizard post

Tags: story-identification, manga

Manga where the mc is kicked from a royal wizard post. He meets his former classmate who is an adventurer.  She tells him to join her and his two other friends. The party's name is lasting period. Party members are four, the MC is the offensive mage, a defensive mage, healer who doubles up as an archer, and lastly a spearman. The plot revolves around both the mages. I hate the fact that i forgot the name of this manga.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Answer (score 1):

Could this be *[The Banished Court Magician Aims to Become the Strongest](https://myanimelist.net/manga/146242/Mikata_ga_Yowasugite_Hojo_Mahou_ni_Tesshiteita_Kyuutei_Mahoushi_Tsuihou_sarete_Saikyou_wo_Mezashimasu)* (AKA *Mikata ga Yowa Sugite Hojo Mahou ni Toushite Ita Kyuutei Mahoushi, Tsuihou Sarete Saikyou wo Mezasu*)?

> "This party doesn't need an incompetent magician who can only use
> supportive magic. You're fired, Alec Huguette."
>
> Suddenly, Alec, a court magician who had joined the crown prince's
> party to help him conquer dungeons—was banished from the party. And
> not just the party, but the crown prince's harassment has banished him
> from the royal palace as well, and a friend from the "magic academy"
> approached Alec, who was at his wit's end.
>
> "Hey, Alec. Do you want to try to conquer the dungeon with us again?"
>
> And so, together with the friends he used to party with, Alec begins
> his second journey in life. This is the adventure story of a former
> court magician who had been abandoned.
>
> Four years ago, the "Lasting Period," a party of four that had been
> called "legendary," has gradually spread its name around the world.
>
> [image]